# Trying to add get_the_title hook to this line

Tags: php, css, wordpress

[image]

Hi trying to add the get_the_title() to this line of code:

```html
<?php echo '<textarea style="margin-left: 15px; width: 246px;" rows="3" cols="28" placeholder="I am interested in:" name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';?>
```

The final effect is always defaulting the "I am interested in:" then a space and then the Post Title.

Here is more of the code using:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background-color: #f8f8f8; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">
  <?php echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';?>
  <?php echo '<h5>';?>
  <?php echo 'Ask a question <br/>';?>
  <?php echo '</h5>';?>
  <?php echo '<p>';?>
  <?php echo '<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="text" placeholder="Your Name (required)" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="29" />';?>
  <?php echo '</p>';?>
  <?php echo '<p>';?>
  <?php echo '<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="email" placeholder="E-mail (required)" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="29" />';?>
  <?php echo '</p>';?>
  <?php echo '<p>';?>
   <?php echo '<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="text" placeholder="Phone (required)" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) : '' ) . '" size="29" />';?>
   <?php echo '</p>';?>
   <?php echo '<p>';?>
   <?php echo '<textarea style="margin-left: 15px; width: 246px;" rows="3" cols="28" placeholder="I am interested in: " name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';?>
   <?php echo '</p>';?>
   <?php echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Contact Agent" style="border-radius: 5px; color: #fff; margin-left: 15px; width: 247px; height: 38px; background-color: #27ae60;"></p>';?>
   <?php echo '</form>';?>
  <?php echo '<p style="font-size: x-small; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 22px;">';?>
  <?php echo 'By sending a request you agree to our Privacy Policy';?>
  <?php echo '</p>';?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution that worked:

```html
....placeholder="I am interested in: '.get_the_title().' "....
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right:

```
<?php echo '<textarea style="margin-left: 15px; width: 246px;" rows="3" cols="28" placeholder="I am interested in:" name="cf-message">I am interested in: ' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';?>
```

Comment: Hi Yaakov, thank you for replying. In the placeholder html call I already have the I am interested in:. What I am trying to add is the post title of what ever post this form is on behind the placeholder I am interested in: like I have shown in the picture I just added.